# Chaos Monkey equivalent for Docker?

Tags: docker

Is there a tool out there like Chaos Monkey that will randomly shutdown docker containers, so we can test the resiliency of our system?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Pumba](https://github.com/gaia-adm/pumba). It can be started as a docker container to start randomly killing other containers

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

https://github.com/giantswarm/mizaru

I think this is the stuff you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks I'll look in to that

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [Blockade](https://github.com/dcm-oss/blockade). 
You can play with network partition, blockade underneath uses both iptables and tc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Docker specific, but testing resiliency is more than about just killing Docker containers.

If you want to degrade network performance, tamper with HTTP request/response etc. you could look at [Muxy](https://github.com/mefellows/muxy). I use it often in (e.g. docker compose) setups to test how the overall set of Docker services behave.

Note that I am the author of the tool.